# my program has a page(main page) that has 5 radio button in it and a button "ok",and I have 5 other Frame

Tags: python, tkinter, radio-button, show

my program has a page(main page) that has 5 radio button in it and a button "ok",and I have 5 other Frame. I want my program to go to these frames after clicking the "ok" ( based on the chosen radio button).

when the "ok" is clicked it will call a lambda and get the value of chosen radiobutton and based on this value put the correct string (veg) which represent the name of the page we want to go to. I don't know where to call this:

`controller.show_frame(veg)`

if i put : controller.show_frame(veg) in the okclick function I receive this error: 
Exception in Tkinter callback Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\tkinter_init_.py", line 1699, in call return self.func(*args) File "C:/Users/AI/PycharmProjects/KBS/alaki.py", line 37, in  button2 = ttk.Button(self, command=lambda : okclick(v) ,text='OK', width=25) File "C:/Users/AI/PycharmProjects/KBS/alaki.py", line 65, in okclick controller.show_frame(veg) NameError: name 'controller' is not defined

here is the code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from win32print import StartPage


class KBSapp(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        tk.Tk.iconbitmap(self,default="icon.ico")
        tk.Tk.wm_title(self, "Diseases and pests of vegetable crops")
        container = tk.Frame(self, width=200, height=200, bg='black')
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames = {}

        for F in (StartPage,carrot,celery, potato, wheat, bean):
            frame = F(container, self)
            self.frames[F] = frame
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.show_frame(StartPage)

    def show_frame(self, cont):
        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise( )


class StartPage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        label = tk.Label(self, width=0, height=20)
        label.pack()

        button2 = ttk.Button(self, command=lambda : okclick(v) ,text='OK', width=25)
        button2.pack( )

        v = tk.IntVar( )
        self.option1 = ttk.Radiobutton(self,  text="Carrot", variable=v, value=1);self.option1.pack( )
        self.option2 = ttk.Radiobutton(self,  text="Celery", variable=v, value=2);self.option2.pack( )
        self.option3 = ttk.Radiobutton(self,  text="potato", variable=v, value=3);self.option3.pack( )
        self.option4 = ttk.Radiobutton(self,  text="wheat", variable=v, value=4);self.option4.pack( )
        self.option5 = ttk.Radiobutton(self,  text="bean", variable=v, value=5);self.option5.pack( )
        v.set(1)  # initializing the choice




def okclick(v):
    global veg
    input1=v.get( )
    if input1==1:
        veg="carrot"
    if input1==2:
        veg='celery'
    if input1==3:
        veg='potato'
    if input1==4:
        veg='wheat'
    if input1==5:
        veg='bean'
    print(veg)

class carrot(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        label = tk.Label(self, width=0, height=20)
        label.pack( )
        button3 = ttk.Button(self, command=lambda : controller.show_frame(celery) , text='celery', width=25)
        button3.pack( )

class celery(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        label = tk.Label(self, width=0, height=20)
        label.pack( )
        button4 = ttk.Button(self, command=lambda : controller.show_frame(potato) , text='potato', width=25)
        button4.pack( )

class potato(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        label = tk.Label(self, width=0, height=20)
        label.pack( )
        button4 = ttk.Button(self, command=lambda : controller.show_frame(wheat) , text='wheat', width=25)
        button4.pack( )


class wheat(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        label = tk.Label(self, width=0, height=20)
        label.pack( )
        button4 = ttk.Button(self, command=lambda : controller.show_frame(bean) , text='bean', width=25)
        button4.pack( )

class bean(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        label = tk.Label(self, width=0, height=20)
        label.pack( )
        button4 = ttk.Button(self, command=lambda : controller.show_frame(StartPage) , text='StartPage', width=25)
        button4.pack( )


app = KBSapp( )
app.mainloop( )
```

Comment: What is 'the error'?  Please,  edit your question with the error you're getting and any details of what you've done to try and debug it.

Comment: if i put :       controller.show_frame(veg)  in the  okclick function I receive this error:     Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1699, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:/Users/AI/PycharmProjects/KBS/alaki.py", line 37, in <lambda>
    button2 = ttk.Button(self, command=lambda : okclick(v) ,text='OK', width=25)
  File "C:/Users/AI/PycharmProjects/KBS/alaki.py", line 65, in okclick
    controller.show_frame(veg)
NameError: name 'controller' is not defined

Comment: Not everyone will search through the comments for the error. Please edit your question and add the error text you just commented.